# Meaning of "over in"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, prepositional-phrases

I read this sentence in a book:

> I just took part in a study over in the Psychology Department.

Why do we add *over* in front of *in the* here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Over" in that context is just a mild intensifier expressing that the location mentioned is some physical distance away. Cf. "Over There" — the song sung by American troops in the 1st World War in which Europe, way across the Atlantic Ocean, was referred to as "Over There."

Comment: "Over in the Psychology Department" as opposed to "here in the Psychology department".

Comment: ...or 'here in the English department'.

Comment: How about *yon(der) in the* or *in yon(der)*?

Comment: US troops stationed in the UK during and after WWII were said to be 'Over-paid, over-sexed and over here'!

Comment: @Barrie: Yes, and it's a good thing for England they *were* over there. That's an example of, if not biting, at least resenting the hand that fed you.